# convert a big landscape table to png

Tags: latex

I want to generate a standalone png table. I have to include it in the google doc. I have tried to take screenshots and similar solutions, but the visibility is not good. I tried using a standalone class and available solutions, but it is not working. Also, in my case, one of the columns shows references. So, I want to convert a big landscape table to png. The references should not appear on the png image.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs, graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
 \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\caption{Comparison column.}\label{tab:column}
\small
\tabcolsep=0.077cm
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{17}{c}@{}}

\toprule
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\thead{\textbf{Ref.}}}  & 
  \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{column 1 Details}} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{column 2 Details}} &
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{column 3 Details}} \\
  \cline{2-17} 
% \midrule
 & 
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column-\\\it name}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column\\ \it name }} &
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\thead{\it column}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column\\\it name}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column-\\\it name}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column\\ \it name}} &
   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column-\\\it name}} &
   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column-\\\it name\\ \it name}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column}} &
   \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column\\\it name}} &
  \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{\it column\\\it namename}} \\ \cline{5-9}
    & 
    &
   &
   &
   
  \thead{\it column\\\it name} &
  \thead{\it column-\\\it name} &
  \thead{\it{column}\\\it name} &
  \thead{\it column\\\it name} &
  \thead{\it column\\\it name} 
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   &
   \\
%   \hline
\midrule
~\cite{adams1995hitchhiker} & any thing & $\approx$ & E\&E & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO &  \faCircleO & data & \faAdjust & \faAdjust  & \faAdjust  & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO 
 \\ \hline
 ~\cite{adams1995hitchhiker} & any thing & \faCircleO & E\&E & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO &  \faCircleO & data & \faAdjust & \faAdjust  & \faAdjust  & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO & \faCircleO 
 \\ \hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \textbf{?}~Guess, \faCircleO~Not there, \faAdjust~Partially, \faCircle~given.
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}
\expandafter\ifx\csname url\endcsname\relax
  \def\url#1{\texttt{#1}}\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname urlprefix\endcsname\relax\def\urlprefix{URL }\fi
\expandafter\ifx\csname href\endcsname\relax
  \def\href#1#2{#2} \def\path#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem{adams1995hitchhiker}
A.~, A.~, Cyber-physical systems, The authors
  12~(1) (2011) 161--166.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you use imagemagick to convert from the pdf to png, you can adjust the density to your liking. That being said, I though office gained the ability to include vector graphics like svg a couple of years ago?

Comment: (off-topic: you really shouldn't use two-letter font commands like `\it`)

Comment: So you wanted to say I can include a pdf image in a google doc file? really?

Comment: you said word file

Comment: (I think you can include svg, don't know about pdf, haven't used office in a very long time)

Comment: I am also using the word [or that google doc I assume it's an online version of the word] after a long time. I don't think I can include images other than png.

Comment: google doc != online version of word.

Comment: Please make it clear in your question, what you are asking about

Comment: As said in the first comment, if you use imagemagick to convert from pdf to png, you can adjust the `density` parameter to get a better result

Comment: I can not generate a standalone table [landscape] with refs.